# how to make a third party library as api in android

Tags: android

I am new in android programming.I have created an application (in eclipse using android).it has many features and one of them is tess-two.some of them increases my application size.(like tess-two that increase about 15 MB).so I want to make it as api and if user needs it , download it.tess-two is a project that improrted to eclipse and used ndk and checked islibrary (properties -> android) and used in my main project(so in my project it is in bin folder).

I am sorry that my question is complicated or I asked it badly.

Comment: Recommend you develop using the supported env: Android Studio, not Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

A recommended option is to put tess-two in a separate app. This new app has no user interface. When installed, it exposes an API you (or potentially other apps) can use. This API could be, depending on your needs, a ContentProvider or a service\activity that handles an intent you create.

When the user of your main app asks for a feature that uses tess-two you will check if your API is available (i.e the intent is resolved or the content provider is available) and if not, direct the user to the play store.

An alternative option is to dynamically download code into a new classloader. It's both complicated and forbidden by Play Store policy.